# Correct sentence SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

COL. A& B OREADY INSERT

My sample data:

```
A          B           K       P       M
--         --         --       --      -- 
2          5                       
3          5
```

Query:

```
select  
    ([A] + [B]) AS [K], 
    ([A] * [B]) AS [P],
    -- can I write like this?
    ([P]-[K]) AS [M] 
    -- or must I write :
    -- ([A]+[B]) - ([A]*[B]) /* sometimes the formula is very long
from  
    TB
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Maybe you can show us the real entire formula and the current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You Can write this Using Sub Query. Check Below Query.

```
    select *,([P]-[K]) as M
    From
    (
    select A,B,([A]+[B]) AS [K], ([A]*[B]) AS [P],
    FROM TB
    )a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit thin, but one trick you could use to avoid writing out repetitive parts of a formula would be to "define" various pieces in a subquery, and then use those defined aliases in an outer query.  Something like this:

```
SELECT t.[K] - t.[P] AS some_value
FROM
(
    SELECT ([A]+[B]) AS [K],
           ([A]*[B]) AS [P]
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

Of course, you put the subquery into a CTE, but for explanation purposes I prefer what I have given above.

**Edit:**

As @juergen pointed out, using this subquery trick usually makes the overall query much slower.  So you need to decide whether the brevity you get with the subquery is worth the potential tradeoff in slower performance.

Comment: BTW subqueries can make the query way slower.

Comment: @juergend Yes, I knew this, didn't think this was the focus of the OP though.

Comment: Fair enough but I think speed is always an issue when querying databases.

Answer (score 0):

Column aliases cannot be used in same select statement it  can be used at your outer query select statement.

```
select [A],[B],[K],[P],[K]-[P] AS [M] FROM
(
select  [A],[B],
([A]+[B]) AS [K], 
([A]*[B]) AS [P]
) AS A
```